# how to receive streaming data using flask in python program

Tags: python, json, flask

I really need some simple example to demonstrate how to receive streaming data sent from remote side.

I spent several hours online to search example code, but all I found is to sent streaming data to remote side, not receive from remote side.

The stream data is in JSON format, looks like:

```
15:15
15:17
15:20
15:21
15:22
```

I would greatly appreciate someone who could provide me some simple, "hello-world like", examples which could receive such data. I am very new to flask.

Comment: The web application shouldn't be the handler for incoming streaming content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web applications are usually designed for sending data to clients not being clients themselves. (AKA, the client has to initiate the connection, not the application).

Although, your question is a bit vague about how the stream is opened, and who should initiate the calls, here's a small example, that might get you started.

Simple listener that streams the incoming data. Here's an example using [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/):

```
from contextlib import closing
import requests
with closing(requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', stream=True)) as r:
    while r.iter_content:
        # Do something with the stream.. 
        pass
```

Comment: I have another short question. I simply add ' print r ' right after # do something#, and it returns <response [200]> . So this message is actually come from remote side, am I right? I want to build another response for testing my program, how can I do that? Thanks very much

Comment: Nope, this is just a 'nice' way the response object is printed out (aka the `__repr__` property). You can read the response data from either `r.text`, `r,json` or `r.raw`. See here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content

Comment: How to do same using flask test_client get method?